# Making a shared pointer to a new struct with initialisation

Tags: c++, struct

Using libc++ (GNU++11 dialect), LLVM compiler, in Xcode on a Mac.

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float position[3];
    float colour[4];
    float normal[3];
};
```

Currently I'm creating an instance on the heap as follows:

```
Vertex *vertex = new Vertex({{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f},
                            {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
                            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}} );
```

However I want to create a shared pointer instead.
Is the following code the best way of doing it?

```
Vertex v = Vertex( {{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f},
                    {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
                    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}} );

std::shared_ptr<Vertex> vertex = std::make_shared<Vertex>(v);
```

Or should I be creating the `Vertex` using `new` before making a shared pointer?

**Update**

I've tried the following:

```
auto vertex = std::make_shared<PCNVertex>( {{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f},
                                            {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
                                            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}} );
```

as suggested, but I get error `no matching function for call to 'make_shared'`.

Comment: Normally you would just replace `PCNVertex *vertex` with `auto verte2` and `new PCNVertex(...);` with `std::make_shared<PCNVertex>(...);`

Comment: @NathanOliver I've tried that already, I get 'Error:(140, 19) no matching function for call to 'make_shared''

Comment: What compiler are you using and what options are you using to compile with?  Is C++11 turned on?

Comment: Did you include `<memory>`? And what is your `PCNVertex`?

Comment: I've corrected `PCNVertex`, I meant to write just `Vertex`, sorry.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've added info to start of my question

Comment: @JBramble So when you have something like `-std=c++11` in the compiler command?

Comment: It's actually -std=GNU++11 currently. If I change to -std=C++11, I get the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first code snippet (the one right before your update), `std::make_shared` will allocate memory for a new `Vector` and construct it with the given argument `v`, in this case, copy construct. It will work fine.

The second code snippet (in your update) doesn't work because the compiler can't deduce a proper type which matches the argument. The function template std::make_shared is declared as:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

This problem can be solved by a "conversion".

```
auto vertex = std::make_shared<Vertex>(
      Vertex{{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f},
             {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
             {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}} );
```

Comment: Sorry, just realised I never accepted this answer! Done now, thanks.